# "File not found" error in excel VBA while using for loop for iterating multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to fetch information from multiple sheets using FOR loop in excel VBA.

`StrFile = "C:\Users\ABC\INT_Data_" & i & ".xlsx"` - This code is working and iterating the sheets.

But when i am using `StrFile = "C:\Users\ABC\INT_Data_" & i & "*.xlsx"` and renaming the sheets accordingly, it is not working throwing error

> File Not Found.

`ex: INT_Data_1_*.xlsx` should give O/P something like `INT_Data_1_NewFileName.xlsx` but I don't get it.

Comment: Please use code tags when you are posting some code.

Answer (score 0):

Filenames passed as strings don't take wildcard chars like `*`. use `Dir()` instead. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10382861/9538700)